# Voxel Engine, faces are getting bugged when the camera pans out

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I was writting a voxel engine when I got this weird problem with faces.

So when I move away from terrain, everything is breaking. I don't even have an idea how to describe the problem I will post some screenshots.

[image]
[image]

```
camera_projection = bb_perspective(bb_toRadiansReal32(70.0f), ((r32)WINDOW_WIDTH / (r32)WINDOW_HEIGHT), 0.1f, 1000.0f);
```

I found out when I play with the second to last value and change that to 1.0f problem in part disappears. But I don't want to keep this value at 1.0f.

I post definition of this function:

```
static bbMat4 bb_perspective(r32 fov, r32 aspect, r32 near, r32 far) {
  bbMat4 ret(1.0f);

  r32 range = near - far;
  r32 tan_half_fov = tanf(fov / 2.0f);

  ret[0][0] = 1.0f / (tan_half_fov * aspect);
  ret[1][1] = 1.0f / tan_half_fov;
  ret[2][2] = (-near - far) / range;
  ret[2][3] = 2.0f * far * near / range;
  ret[3][3] = 0.0f;
  ret[3][2] = 1.0f;

  return ret;
}
```

I have completely no idea how to deal with this.

Comment: Can you explain what we see in the screenshots and what is wrong with it? Why don't you want to change the znear value to a value that works? Setting the near and far clipping planes to reasonable values is essential. What bit depth do you use for your depth buffer?

Comment: Does it go away if you choose a smaller range from near to far, say 1.0f to 1000.0f?

Comment: Not completely, I have to go futher away with camera to see this bug again.

Comment: And this is what I set up in my renderer init function:
  glFrontFace(GL_CW);
  glCullFace(GL_BACK);
  glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

  // set up depth functions
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_CLAMP);

Comment: problem is not completely described. its complex. need more screenies.

Answer (score 0):

Check your maths.

`ret[2][2] = (-near - far) / range;` doesn't look right. If you look at an existing library (e.g. latest [GLM](https://github.com/g-truc/glm)) you'll be able to see what I mean:

GLM uses `Result[2][2] = (zFar + zNear) / (zFar - zNear);` when clip space is -1 , 1.

Also `ret[2][3] = 2.0f * far * near / range;` should be `ret[3][2] = 2.0f * far * near / range;` and `ret[2][3]` should be 1 - `ret[2][3] = 1;`

As a side note, using your own maths library is almost always not the best idea. Established ones are always rigorously tested by many people. It can be a great exercise though, I have done it myself in the past, but perhaps making use of an existing library to test your output would be a good idea.